# Passing multiple functions as arguments to another function anonymously Python

Tags: python, function

I have code in PHP that I would like to rewrite in Python, but the difficulty is passing functions as arguments. Here is the PHP code:

```
function s($t1, $t2, ...$funcs){
    echo '$t1' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '$t2' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($funcs as $func)
        $func();
    unset($func);
}
```

It is important to me that the transfer method does not require a preliminary declaration of functions:

```
s('a', 'b', function(){print(5);}, function() {print(6);});
```

The question is what is the best way to implement this in python?

I tried to do the same in Python as in PHP, but without success:

```
s('a', 'b', partial(print, 5))
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is the best solution to the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with the python code you have tried.

Comment: What went wrong with your attempt in python?

Comment: @quamrana
To answer your question, dear strict moderator, the biggest mistake in my code is the use of partial. As can be seen from the answers below, elements from the functools library are not needed to solve this problem; it is enough to use lambda functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code adapts to python quite literally:

```py
def s(t1, t2, *funcs):
    print(t1)
    print(t2)
    for func in funcs:
        func()
```

Note how python's `*` replaces PHP's `...` for variable number of arguments.

You can use the `lambda` keyword to declare anonymous inline functions:

```py
s('a', 'b', lambda: print(5), lambda: print(6))
# a
# b
# 5
# 6
```

You can also use `functools.partial`, although this is rarely the best way to do things in python in my opinion:

```py
from functools import partial

s('a', 'b', partial(print, 5), partial(print, 6))
# a
# b
# 5
# 6
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need! Works!

Answer (score 2):

In python you can pass functions as arguments the same way you do with any other object:

```py
def s(t1, t2, funcs):
    # other code
    for func in funcs:
        func()

def partial():
    print(6)

s('a', 'b', [lambda : print(5), partial])
```

where lambda is a small function with no name.

Example with *args so that you can pass a variable number of arguments without the need for a list.

```py
def s(t1, t2, *funcs):
    # other code
    for func in funcs:
        func()

def partial():
    print(6)

s('a', 'b', lambda : print(5), partial)
```

Comment: Thank you. print(5) and print(6) is just examples, I need the ability to pass different numbers of lambda functions.

Comment: You're welcome! You can also use *args to pass a variable number of arguments to the s function without using a list.

Comment: TypeError: modulator_page.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'.

Comment: @upkagefa you are right, lamdba expected one an argument. I changed it to expect none

Answer (score 1):

You might use `*` operator to create variadic function, functions are 1st class citizens in `python`, therefore you might pass them as arguments. Consider following example

```
def uno():
    print(1)
def dos():
    print(2)
def tres():
    print(3)
def execute_functions(*args):
    for func in args:
        func()
print("---")
execute_functions(uno)
print("---")
execute_functions(uno, dos, tres)
print("---")
```

gives output

```
---
1
---
1
2
3
---
```

Comment: This is not a very good solution. If the functions uno, does, tres are not used anywhere else, then their declaration clogs up the code. And if there are a lot of such functions, then this can seriously impair the readability of the code.